# Select rows before and after matching row in specified order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of `users` with `points` column in it. User `id` is not autoincrement, but it is user ID from Twitter.

I'm trying to select user by `username` (so always 1 user) and select 10 rows before it and 10 rows after it.

Also, it should be ordered by points and I should get ranking of selected user.

I'm using Laravel 4 and Eloquent, but I'm pretty sure it can't be done with Eloquent.

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+
| id        | username     | vote_count |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 123456789 | user1        |        150 |
| 123456789 | user2        |        101 |
| 123456789 | user3        |         90 |
| 123456789 | user4        |         88 |
| 123456789 | user5        |         70 |
| 123456789 | user6        |         67 |
| 123456789 | user7        |         65 |
| 123456789 | user8        |         55 |
| 123456789 | user9        |         54 |
| 123456789 | user10       |         45 |
| 123456789 | user11       |         44 |
| 123456789 | user12       |         42 |
+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

Let's say I want to order this table by `vote_count`, than select `user5` and select 2 users that are before and after it in given order.

Hope I'm being clear with this one

Comment: *select 10 rows before it and 10 rows after it* What does that mean? Can you show example data?

Comment: I have edited a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d6fee/6)

```
select * from

(
select * from
(
select * from t where vote_count<=
                      (select vote_count 
                        from t 
                        where username ='user5')

ORDER BY vote_count desc
LIMIT 3 
) as T1  
UNION
select * from
(
select * from t where vote_count>
                      (select vote_count 
                        from t 
                        where username ='user5')

ORDER BY vote_count ASC
LIMIT 2 
) as T2
) as T3 ORDER BY VOTE_COUNT DESC
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Is it possible to keep track of row index?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

```
 (SELECT id, vote_count
 FROM   `table`
 WHERE  id > 123456789
 LIMIT  10)
UNION
(SELECT id, vote_count
 FROM   `table`
 WHERE  id <= 123456789
 LIMIT  10)
ORDER  BY vote_count
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d6fee/18) 
  `select * from ( (select A.vote_count,A.username from t A join t B on A.vote_count<B.vote_count where B.username='user5' order by A.vote_count DESC limit 2)
UNION
(select A.vote_count,A.username from t A join t B on A.vote_count>=B.vote_count where B.username='user5' order by A.vote_count limit 3)) as T order by vote_count desc`